Anychart scroller connected to two charts
Trying to connect the scroller of either chart so that when you scroll on one chart it also scrolls on the other.
As far as I can understand, the 'stock' chart available from anychart has access to the 'setRange' functionality - however I need to use the Box charts and cannot find an alternative
    var stage = anychart.graphics.create('container');
    var chart_stage = anychart.graphics.create('container-chart');
    var chart_stage2 = anychart.graphics.create('container-chart-2');

    var chart1 = anychart.box();
    chart1.data(testdata);

    chart1.container('chart1');
    chart1.xScroller(true);
    chart1.container(chart_stage).draw();

    var chart2 = anychart.box();
    chart2.data(testdata);
    chart2.xScroller(true);
    chart2.container('chart1');
    chart2.container(chart_stage2).draw();

    var scroller = anychart.standalones.scroller();
    var scroller2 = anychart.standalones.scroller();
    scroller.parentBounds(10, 0, 400, 60);
    scroller2.parentBounds(10, 100, 400, 60);

    // Set range.
    scroller.setRange(0.1, 0.5);
    scroller2.setRange(0.1, 0.5);


    scroller.container(stage);
    scroller2.container(stage);

    scroller.container(stage).draw();


    scroller2.draw();

    function synchronizeScrollers(sourceChart, targetChart) {
        sourceChart.listen('scrollerchange', function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            scroller.setRange(e.startRatio, e.endRatio);
            chart2.setRange(e.startRatio, e.endRatio);
            e.startRatio = 0;
            e.endRatio = 0.1;
        })
    }

    synchronizeScrollers(chart1, chart2);

